# What is the value returned by power(2,5) given the following code?

Tags: python

```
def power(x,n):
    'computes x to the power of n'

    value = 1
    if n > 0:
        value = power(x, n//2)
        if n%2 == 0:
            value = value*value

        else:
            value = value*value*x

    return value
```

So I know the answer is 32 (as told by my lecturer) but I can't seem to figure out how to obtain that value when I step through the code. Could anyone break this code down for me?

Comment: put some `print`s and go through them

Comment: You probably got the downvotes because SO is for helping you fix _your_ code, not explaining someone else's code. But take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36645766/4014959) for an example of adding `print` calls to recursive code to help you trace what it does.

Comment: Recommended sites where they explain codes?

Comment: Nevermind, found one. (Y)

Comment: SO is not there to do homework in your stead. Right now your question does not show any research effort. As stated [there](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: Priyansh Goel's answer has explained the basic algorithm of your code. And I'm sure you can find more in-depth explanations elsewhere that go into the details of how this recursive implementation works. But to _really understand_ it you need to see what it's doing for yourself. Which is why we're recommending you chuck some print calls in there.

Comment: But it isn't homework. I just needed clarification. And I got that thanks to Priyansh Goel. Dw, won't be asking questions like this again.

Comment: If you don't get 32 when you manually step through that code then you must be doing something wrong. But with no further info from you we have _no idea_ what that is, and where your misunderstanding lies. It's pretty hard for us to provide clarification when we don't know what particular aspect is unclear to you.

Comment: Nothing was clear. I actually added in the post that I'm new to Python and the logic behind the code was hazy but that got edited out for some reason. All good now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 
[exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

So, basically 2^5 is same as  2 * 2^(2) * 2^(2) and 2^2 is same as 2^1 * 2 ^ 1 . And that is the idea it uses.